# Though I increase number of cpu, hash rate does not increase

Tags: cpu-mining, gpu-mining, hashrate, xmr-stak-amd

I am new at mining. My first experience is with monero with using xmr-stak on supportxmr pool. My problem is that when I mine with 4 cpu I get about 150 H/s. This is the default configs by the way, I mean when I compile the code, in the cpu file there is this:

```
"cpu_threads_conf" :
[
{ "low_power_mode" : false, "no_prefetch" : true, "affine_to_cpu" : 0 },
{ "low_power_mode" : false, "no_prefetch" : true, "affine_to_cpu" : 1 },
{ "low_power_mode" : false, "no_prefetch" : true, "affine_to_cpu" : 2 },
{ "low_power_mode" : false, "no_prefetch" : true, "affine_to_cpu" : 3 },

],
```

But when I increase these numbers (I got 4 core and 8 process, I am using ubuntu, when I open the system monitor I see 8 cpu) like below, I got more lower (about 60) H/s.

```
"cpu_threads_conf" :
[
{ "low_power_mode" : false, "no_prefetch" : true, "affine_to_cpu" : 0 },
{ "low_power_mode" : false, "no_prefetch" : true, "affine_to_cpu" : 1 },
{ "low_power_mode" : false, "no_prefetch" : true, "affine_to_cpu" : 2 },
{ "low_power_mode" : false, "no_prefetch" : true, "affine_to_cpu" : 3 },
{ "low_power_mode" : false, "no_prefetch" : true, "affine_to_cpu" : 4 },
{ "low_power_mode" : false, "no_prefetch" : true, "affine_to_cpu" : 5 },
{ "low_power_mode" : false, "no_prefetch" : true, "affine_to_cpu" : 6 },
],
```

This happens when tried it with 5,6,7 or 8 cpu. Why is that? Should not it increase when I increase the number of cpus?

One more question, actually I think I am mining with bot cpu and gpu, how can I check that if I am using gpu for mining or not? Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whilst your CPU may have the *ability* to run 8 threads, it may not have enough *cache* for mining with 8 threads. With Monero, you need 2MB CPU cache per thread. So for 8 threads you'd need a CPU cache of 16MB available.

If you run more threads than you have cache for, it will slow down the hashing.

Comment: L1d cache:           32K
L1i cache:           32K
L2 cache:            256K
L3 cache:            8192K This is my cpu cache informations. I guess it is 8MB is it right? So I can do mine with 4 thread max?

Comment: You definitely don't have enough cache to mine effectively with 8 threads. Max for your CPU is 4 threads.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. Can you say anything about my second question? And I would like to ask something else if you do not mind. I believe I get low hash rate (150), I got i7 8th gen intel cpu. I know I can not get much xmr with 1 cpu but I am just testing and learning the system. I guess I am missing some simple things to increase my hashrate. I did not do anything else than just setting up xmr-stak and run it. Can you suggest me something to increase hash rate other than overclocking? Thanks a lot,

Answer (score -1):

You can log out of window manager,`ssh` or ALT + F7 into console and run `xmr-stak` from CLI ... Shave a few percent off your CPU load